# False statements in intuitionistic logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, kripke-models

In the explanations of intuitionistic logic I've been reading ([1](https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/03/28/the-kripke-model-for-intuition-1), [2](https://umm-csci.github.io/senior-seminar/seminars/spring2022/rauerslides.pdf), [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf)), especially in the explanation of the semantics, I don't understand how a proposition being false influences the situation.

These explanations say something like "$W \Vdash p$ iff $p$ is true in $W$". That sounds clear enough, and then they continue and define the other operators. What I don't get is, when $W \not\Vdash p$? In source [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf) they later show some diagrams where actually in every world each proposition has a truth value, either 0 or 1, so in that case I guess when $W(p) = 0$ then $W \not\Vdash p$. I feel like, for this to be the case, the explanation should have contained a short line saying, $\Vdash$ is the minimal relation following these definitions, otherwise it would be allowed to have $W \Vdash p$ even though $W(p) = 0$.

However [1](https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/03/28/the-kripke-model-for-intuition-1) makes me doubt my interpretation for [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf), as it contains the following:

> you can think of intuitionistic logic as a logic where at a given point of time, a statement can have three truth values: T (top), which means provably true; ⏊ (bottom) which means provably false, and unproved

Following this line of reasoning, whenever $p$ is unproved, you can have neither $\Vdash$ nor $\not\Vdash$. But I feel this would make the definition of negation in [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf) useless...? As a computer scientist with only a passing knowledge of formal logic, this is were my brain sputters to a halt.

My questions:

- <strike>Is the explanation in [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf) correct in that in a given world, a $p$ is either assigned $0$ or $1$?</strike> (This is the case, as stated on slide 27.)
- Is it a safe way to model intuitionistic logic, or does it exclude true statements/proofs that the description in [1](https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/03/28/the-kripke-model-for-intuition-1) would allow?
- What is the canonical source I can read for a a semantics for inuitionistic propositional logic that is broadly accepted as standard (or, at least has some degree of consensus around it)?

(As a side note: [1](https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/03/28/the-kripke-model-for-intuition-1) seems to skip defining negation for formulas, is that just an oversight or could [3](https://pgadey.ca/seminar/Albert_Intuitionistic.pdf) have skipped defining it, as it is implied by the other definitions?)

Thanks for any explanatations or tips for other reading material!

Comment: 1st question not clear... $p$ is an *atom*: thus either it is True in a state W or it is False; see source linked in 3 slide 25 and 27: for each state W function $\pi_W$ (truth assignment) is a fucntion from atomic propositions to booleans $\{ 0, 1 \}$.

Comment: Maybe useful [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)

Comment: I missed the part on slide 27, that answers my first question, thanks a lot! The stanford link is very good but a bit dense for me as a non-logician. I guess I'll have to try harder next time I read it.

Comment: But this does not hold for **every** formula: there are "conjectures" like the [Twin prome conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Twin_prime_conjecture) i.e. formuals not (yet) proved neither refuted.

Comment: Canonical sources? many... Some ML textbook have chapter on IL; see e.g. [van Dalen](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-3-540-85108-0), **Ch.5 Intuitionistic Logic**.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> “ whenever $p$ is unproved, you can have neither ⊩ nor ⊮.”

This isn’t correct. Consider the Law of the Excluded Middle $A \lor \neg A$. Intuitionistic Logic doesn’t have to have this formula satisfied at an arbitrary world, but that doesn’t mean it has to be false in every world in a given model. That of course would be inconsistent, since Intuitionism proves the double-negated version.

In particular, there is a difference between

$w \not \Vdash p$

and

$w \Vdash \neg p$

as the latter means $v \not \Vdash p$ whenever $w \le v$, while the former simply means the value of $p$ is $0$ at $w$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense (to the classical part of my brain). Is it too strict to say that for w and any v >= w, any p that occurs in the formula is defined in w? So every world in the model must assign either 0 or 1 to any propositional variable in the formula?  Or do some intuitionistic logic distinguish that as well, meaning, some u < w might not define p, w(p) = 0, and for some v >= w, v(p) = 1? It seems that my sources seem to have different opinions about this, but they are not explicit about it.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “defined at $w$”, but all it takes for $v(p)$ to be $0$ is for $p$ to not be satisfied at $w$.

Comment: Maybe I can clarify: in source (1) of my question, worlds are basically mappings from propositional variables to truth values. E.g. slide 28 has root world w0 with: p -> 0, q -> 0, r -> 0. This world/mapping is defined for p, q, and r, but not for some external propositional variable b. Is each world required to provide a value for each propositional variable in the formula? E.g. if w0 did not have the entry p -> 0, w0 would not be defined for p. Is that allowed?

Comment: Note that standard Intuitionistic tautologies still hold at an arbitrary world, even if that proposition isn’t explicitly mentioned in a given model. Basically, assigning a proposition $0$ at a world is just another way of saying it isn’t $1$ at that world, and that holds for propositions not mentioned in the model.